# Stata pie chart: Combine several groups in one slice

Tags: stata, pie-chart

I want to create a pie chart in Stata. The groups are six different world regions:

- East Asia & Pacific
- Latin America & Caribbean
- South Asia
- Europe & Central Asia
- North America
- Sub-Saharan Africa

I use:

```
graph pie, over(region)
```

However, I want to pool the three regions South Asia, Sub-Saharan Africa and Latin America & Caribbean as one group named "Others". How can I do this?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Study this example:

```
sysuse auto, clear
graph pie, over(rep78)
clonevar rep78_2 = rep78
replace rep78_2 = 1 if rep78_2 == 2
label def rep78_2 1 "1 or 2"
label val rep78_2 rep78_2
graph pie, over(rep78_2)
```

Principles are

1. Don't use pie charts any way. They are suitable only for small children or senior executives. Bar or dot charts are almost always better.
2. Setting #1 aside, create a copy of your variable. `clonevar` has the simple merit that any variable label will be copied automatically.
3. Combine categories as desired.
4. Usually, explain that by creating and/or editing value labels.
5. Draw your graph.

Comment: Here's [a nice example](https://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/save_the_pies_for_dessert.pdf) of how bad pies can be.